# Java - Do not overwrite with bufferedwriter

Tags: java, line, overwrite, bufferedwriter

I have a program that add persons to an arraylist. What I'm trying to do is add these persons to a text file as well but the program overwrites the first line so the persons get erased.

How do I tell the compiler to write at the next free line?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Logic {

File file;
FileWriter fw;
FileReader fr;
BufferedWriter bw;
ArrayList<Person> person;

public Logic() {
    try {
        file = new File("register.txt");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    person = new ArrayList<Person>();
}

// Add person
public void addPerson(String name, int tele) {
    person.add(new Person(name, tele));
    savePerson(name, tele);
}

// Save person to external file
public void savePerson(String name, int tele) {
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(file.getName());
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        String tel = Integer.toString(tele);
        bw.write(name + "\t" + tel);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("skrev inte ut med buffered");
    }
}

// Går in i alla objekt av klassen Person och skriver ut toString i
// textArean
public void visaAlla(JTextArea textRuta) {
    textRuta.setText("");
    // for(Person p:person)
    // {
    // textRuta.append(p.toString());
    // }

    try {
        fr = new FileReader(file.getName());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String str;

        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            textRuta.append(str);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("gickcinte ");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`FileWriter` takes an [optional boolean argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) which specifies whether it should append to or overwrite the existing content. Pass in `true` if you want to open the file for writing in append mode.