# BufferedWriter keeps erasing what I wrote

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I have the following class:

```
public class test{
    private static final File testfile = new File("filename")//imaginary file name
private static BufferedWriter writer = null;
    public void test1(){
      writer = new OutStreamWriter(newFileOutputStream(testfile));
      writer.write("hello");
      writer.close();
}
    public void test2(){
      writer = new OutStreamWriter(newFileOutputStream(testfile));
      writer.write("hello");
      writer.close();
}

}
```

I want both of them to write to the same file whenever called and I create bufferedwriters inside each of the methods. However, once i call close on to the buffered writer, it cannot be opened again. How do I avoid this so I can call both methods multiple times?

Comment: Please show us your code so we know how to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you had the same issue of this poster [Java - Do not overwrite with bufferedwriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588045/java-do-not-overwrite-with-bufferedwriter)

Sanjay T. Sharma says:

"FileWriter takes an optional boolean argument which specifies whether it should append to or overwrite the existing content. Pass in true if you want to open the file for writing in append mode."

Comment: is there anyway to do it without passing in the text file as an argument?

Comment: what do you mean "text file"? You mean the name/location of the file?

Comment: It doesn't take a text file as an argument. It takes in a file object: 
File file = new File("filename.ext");